# Test for equality in a nested list and append results to another list?

Tags: python

I'm solving a challenge and have this list of students with scores:

```
arr = [['E', 21.0], ['A', 20.0], ['B', 20.0], ['C', 19.0], ['D', 19.0]]
```

I would like the students that have scored the second highest to have their data stored in a second list `fin_arr`. If there is only one student, then store only that data. Which means that the above list should return:

```
print(fin_arr)
[['A', 20.0],
 ['B', 20.0]]
```

My solution works but that only applies to specific indexes where one can *assume* that the second highest scores are found at 2nd last and 3rd last indexes (the list has to be not more than 5 entries). But what if the list is a sorted list like the above? I found several ways to evaluate lists but haven't come across specifically checking for equality for indexes within subindexes and I'm lost in my IDE's history of commands. What could be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Would converting your list to another data structure which allows ordering based on a property (such as a dataframe or an dictionary) help?

Comment: You could post an answer for that if you like. There is no constraint to which data structure is required, but the way the whole code block (I did not display it here) is written, it might mess up the whole thing. Nevertheless, I would like to see it with a dict too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using the `np.sort()` and `np.unique` to get the second best grade, and then by using a list comprehension.

Here is what it could look like :

```
import numpy as np

arr = [['E', 21.0], ['A', 20.0], ['B', 20.0], ['C', 19.0], ['D', 19.0]]

second_best_grade = np.sort(np.unique([x[1] for x in arr]))[-2]
result = [x[0] for x in arr if x[1] == second_best_grade]
```

---

Output :

```
['A', 'B']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
arr = [['E', 21.0], ['A', 20.0], ['B', 20.0], ['C', 19.0], ['D', 19.0]]

from itertools import groupby
from pprint import pprint

arr = [[*g] for v, g in groupby(sorted(arr, key=lambda k: k[-1]), lambda k: k[-1])]

if len(arr) > 1:
    pprint(arr[1], width=20)
else:
    print([])
```

Prints:

```
[['A', 20.0],
 ['B', 20.0]]
```

Comment: slightly more efficient to use `operator.itemgetter(1)` instead of `lambda`. also youcould avoid your if-else logic hackily with `(arr[1:2] or [[]])[0]`